# How to write a MySQL query in Java with user parameters with dates

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, jdbc

First of all guys thanks for the previous help and advice. I am only learning databases and MySQL, so please bear with me while I ask so major newbie type questions.

I'm entering 2 parameters, one is a string and the other is a date. I then want to then output of a another value. The string is straight forward but I'm unable to compare the dates properly. If the dates and the strings match then that is the record I'm looking for

Here is a copy of the table

```
    private String agentDetail = "CREATE TABLE AgentDetail (" 
        + "idNo INT(64) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"  
        + "initials VARCHAR(2)," 
        + "agentDate DATE,"  
        + "agentCount INT(64), "
        + "PRIMARY KEY(idNo))";
```

The problem is that it always brings back all the dates, both the correct and incorrect results

and here is the code that I am currently using

```
    protected void getAgentIdNo (Connection con, PreparedStatement preStatement,
                ResultSet result, String initials, Date myDate) {
        try {
            preStatement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM AGENTDETAIL");
            result = preStatement.executeQuery();

            while (result.next()) {
                if (result.getString("initials").equals(initials)){
                    if (myDate.compareTo(result.getDate("agentDate")) == 0){
                        System.out.println("The date and initials matched !!");
                        System.out.println("The id no is " + result.getint("idNo");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("An error occured when reading from the data base");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I also know that this code is far from perfect so feel to suggest a more professional looking code.
Thanks in advance for any all help and support.

Comment: `while (result.next()) {
                if (result.getString("initials").equals(initials)){ if (myDate.compareTo(result.getDate("agentDate")) == 0){` [WHERE clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/select.html): this is what a database is for in the first place...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of make the filter programaticaly, i recommend (in this case to make a SQL query).

You can do something like:

```
protected void getAgentIdNo (Connection con, PreparedStatement preStatement,
                ResultSet result, String initials, Date myDate) {
        try {
            preStatement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM AGENTDETAIL as ag WHERE ag.initial = ? AND date = ?");
            preStatment.setSring(1,initials);
            preStatment.setString(2,date);
            result = preStatement.executeQuery();

        while (result.next()) {
                    System.out.println("The date and initials matched !!");
                    System.out.println("The id no is " + result.getint("idNo");
            }
        }
    }

    catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("An error occured when reading from the data base");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Att: For more detail consult [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) link.

Hope it Helps ^^

Comment: If the parameter is already a date, and the underlying database type is a DATE, then you should probably use `preStatement.setDate(...)`, no?

Comment: ofcourse my friend. but i consider the given code.

Answer (score 1):

That was a bad idea. This is the way to do it:

```
   preStatement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM AGENTDETAIL WHERE initials = ? AND angetDate = ?");
   preStatment.setSring(1, initials);
   preStatment.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

I would like to thank those who have read, reviewed and submitted a poor hacks work. 
There was 2 different schools of thought that emerged and I of course tried both. It is great to try different methods.

I have found that for the code that I'm currently writing while I search for a job, this works very cleanly. However the other responses has also led me to investigate other opportunities that was given.

The segment is part of bigger system which I'm writing to increase my portfolio of work, What I am doing is using Java to create a visual interface, which will only assign one **idNo** to the user per day. The user may then come along and in another segment of code be given the opportunity to manually enter a customer number or alternatively generate one. This is where the **idNo** and **agentCount** numbers come in. By the way I found that command line code programming is way easier. :-)

```
    protected void getAgentIdNo (Connection con, PreparedStatement preStatement, ResultSet result, AgentDetail ageDet) {
        try {
            preStatement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM AGENTDETAIL as ag WHERE ag.initials = ? AND ag.agentDate = ?");
            preStatement.setString(1,ageDet.getInitials());
            preStatement.setDate(2,ageDet.getMyDate());
            result = preStatement.executeQuery();

            while (result.next()) {
                ageDet.setAgeIdNo(result.getInt("idNo"));
                ageDet.setAgeCount(result.getInt("agentCount"));
            }
        }

        catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred when reading from the data base");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Thank you again Guys